# Are "What might happen?" & "who might win?" (the race)" Correct?

Tags: grammar, questions, subjects

In [Cambridge Dictionary Grammar – Questions: wh-questions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions) is found:

> When *what*, *who*, *which* or *whose* is the subject or part of the subject,
> we do not use the auxiliary. We use the word order subject + verb:
>
> - What fell off the wall?
> - Which horse won?
> - Who bought this?
> - Whose phone rang?

Given that *might* is a modal verb and we don't have a subject, are the following questions grammatically correct?

- What might happen?
- Who might win [the race]?

I'm not familiar with this structure. Maybe I don't know the role of the words or The grammar.

Comment: PLease include in your question the name of the book and the exact words it uses to state the "auxiliary rule".

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions

Comment: @Shoe The OP quoted the Cambridge Dictionary. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Lambie. In the original post on ELU the OP said that the quote came from a book. Hence my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Your two queried examples are fine. In fact, a later example given by CD in the article you link to is

> - *Who should we send the invitation to?*

If it is thought that preposition stranding is ugly (it's certainly not ungrammatical per se), we could alter the example to, say,

- *Who/m should we tell first?* ['whom' rather fusty, dated, here]

[Langster](https://langster.org/en/grammar/english/a2/wh-questions) has [reformatted]:

> '... Rule 1: We can form wh- questions using the construction
>
> [wh- question word] + [auxiliary verb (be, do or have)] + [subject] +
> [main verb]: ...
>
> - *Where are you going?*
> - *Who is your best friend?* ...
>
> Note: We can also form wh- questions by using modal verbs instead of
> auxiliary verbs following the construction
>
> [wh- word] + [modal verb] + [subject] + [main verb].
>
> - *Where should I go?* ...
> - *How can I contact you?*

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Those sentences are correct.

The term "auxiliary verb", in that context refers to one specific use of one auxiliary verb, and I imagine it would be clear from the preceding context which it is.

As described immediately above on that page, when forming wh-questions *where the wh- pronoun is an object*, we invert the subject and auxiliary verb of a base sentence. If the base sentence doesn't already have an auxiliary verb, then we use "do".

The point of the section you've quoted is that when forming wh-questions *where the wh- pronoun is the subject*, we don't *add* any auxiliary verb. If you've already got one, like "might", then you just use that.